# ovh.com domain: redirect from IP address to domain name

Tags: web, dns, raspberry-pi, hosting, ovh

- I have raspberry pi web server in my home. It is running on apache2.
  Router ports are redirected and that is ok.
- That web server is accessible from internet by entering my external IP
  address eg. 5.123.123.123
- I want to have a domain name like [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) rather than
  IP address so I bought a domain on OVH.com
- Then inside ovh domain panel, I set up a redirection: [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to
  5.123.123.123
- It does not work, [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) showed some OVH welcome message.
- Then I've read something about DNS servers so I've checked my
  router DNS addresses (1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8) and inserted them into ovh
  dns panel as well.
- Now webpage is not loading at all (no ovh welcome message).

How do I set it up properly?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

At ovh.com create an A record within your DNS zone `mydomain.com` resolving to your public IP `5.123.123.123`, if you also use `www` create another A record.
So at the end you will have 2 A records.

```
A record 'mydomain.com' -> 5.123.123.123
A record 'www.mydomain.com' -> 5.123.123.123
```

Please confirm that your DNS Name servers are the ones provided by ovh.com by running from your Raspberry.

```
dig mydomain.com NS
```